# Flow doesn't recognise refinement inside callback

Tags: flowtype

This code passes the flow check:

```
/* @flow */

function test (list: ?Array<string>): Promise<number> {
  if(list !== null && list !== undefined) {
    return Promise.resolve(list.length)
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(0)
  }
}

console.log(test(null))
```

Whereas the following gets a null check error

```
/* @flow */

function test (list: ?Array<string>): Promise<number> {
  if(list !== null && list !== undefined) {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => list.length)
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(0)
  }
}

console.log(test(null))
```

error:

```
property `length`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
```

Clearly list cannot be `null` so there must be something about the code structure that makes flow unable to recognise this.

I would like to understand what limitation I am hitting and how I can work around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, Flow doesn't know that your type refinement (null check) will hold at the time when `() => list.length` is executed. Inside that callback Flow only looks at the type of list – which says it can be null.

The difference between first and second snippet is that in the second snippet `list` is crossing a function boundary – you're using it in a different function than where you refined its type.

One solution is to extract list.length into a variable, and use that variable in the callback.

```
var length = list.length;
return Promise.resolve().then(() => length)
```

This might also work:

```
var list2: Array<string> = list;
return Promise.resolve().then(() => list2.length)
```

Note that this problem exists even for immediately invoked callbacks, e.g. when using `map` or `forEach`. There is an issue on flow's github about this, but I couldn't find it after a quick search.

Comment: Thanks Nikita! The Caveats section here describes this in detail http://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#caveats